# Do I need to reinstall my OS due to Ruby?

Tags: terminal, install, symlink, ruby, ventura

After trying to upgrade my flutter apps dependencies failed, I've seen a command in the call stack and tried to run it. Now I think I screwed up my local ruby installation with my workarounds. I would like to know if I could retrace my steps to get the original ruby setup without my workarounds, without reinstalling the OS or is it fine the way it is?

Possible important information:

- Ventura: 13.0
- XCode: 14.01

Here is a summary of what I've done:

It was: `sudo gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5`, but instead of fixing stuff it broken even more. Some things were missing and I tried to get back to it's original state.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5227550/6629386) answer. Now I tried to reinstall cocoapods which was apperantly broken by running: `sudo gem install cocoapods`.

Didn't work out because of some missing `ruby/config.h` headers apperantly. After researching I once again found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65481787/6629386):

- 1. I ran: `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby`
- 2. There I created the systemlink: `sudo ln -sf ../../../../Headers/ruby/config.h`
- 3. Afterwards I navigated one folder up: `cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0`
- 4. And here I needed to do something *different* from the original answer: I needed to run: `sudo ln -sf universal-darwin21 universal-darwin22`

I've also installed the xcode cli 14.2 beta thing, but that didn't help either.

Now the App I tried to upgrade is broken, but a different one seems to work, so I think not everything is broken on the system, at least I hope so.

Comment: I got exactly the same issue with my Flutter app: installed XCode 14.0.1, upgraded to Ventura and got broken Ruby 2.6 (`config.h` is gone). Maybe it's not a solution for you, but for me installing Ruby 3.1.2 with `brew` worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118750/1435891. At least I was unblocked and able to build with fastlane. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Passing **RUBY_CFLAGS="-w"** worked for me on MacOS Ventura M1 Max.
example:

```
RUBY_CFLAGS="-w" rbenv install 2.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue Xcode 14.2 14C18 on Monterey, when I try to install cocoapods, (homebrew version is lag behind).
I am luckier than you.
I follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64070241/install-ruby-development-tools-for-gem-installation-on-osx-catalina

And got ruby and the latest cocoapods.
I take all the steps, but I think the essential elements only:

```
xcode-select --install #(for toolchain)
brew install rbenv ruby-build
rbenv install 3.1.2 (your choice) #which will install Ruby from source with regardless to installed Xcode.
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Voila!

Comment: It’s good that you provide the link to StackOverflow, but it’s immensely more helpful if you provide a summary of the essential elements here so it’s not necessary to leave the page/site to get an answer.